# 2 different controllers: hiding elements on the action of one of them

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to do this:

I have this `form-group`:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="search" ng-model="search"/>
</div>
```

that `form-group` must be hidden once this other `form-group` is hidden, BUT, the first `form-group` is from another controller

```
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="LogoutCtrl" ng-show="displayLogout">
   <button type="button">Account Figures</button>
</div>
```

so the let's say that all I need is that once `ng-show=displayLogout` starts working, must do effect on the first `form-group` also.

The thing is that the first `form-group` comes from a controller named `LinesCtrl`, and the second one from `LogoutCtrl` as you see above, but those 2 elements are in the same `navbar`

Comment: Are you trying to have items change on login/logout?

Comment: If you need to keep the controllers separated, then use a variable in the scope of a common parent controller as your flag for hiding/showing the elements.

Comment: @BenFelda yes, I need to display those elements only when the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was suggested in the comments, you can publish the variable `displayLogout` on the common ancestor controller.

For example:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
  <div ng-controller="LogoutCtrl" ng-show="displayLogout">
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
    <div class="form-group" ng-show="displayLogout">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in `ParentCtrl` controller, set:

```
.controller("ParentCtrl", function($scope){
   // ...
   $scope.displayLogout = user.isLoggedIn; // whatever you have there
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a 'loggedIn' bool in a parent controller will fix your issue.  A problem will come up if you need to use that bool elsewhere in your app.  I typically place the loggedin bool in an auth service that handles login and logoff requests.  This service sends a broadcast out once the login or logoff event has completely finished and all app necessary data has been retrieved.  Each controller/service/directive listens for these events and handles them however they need to.

Since authentication is used globally in most apps, it is a good candidate for using Angulars events.